# Inject content in component from other component using Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have your usual admin dashboard (Core-UI) which I'm modifying for my own needs. I have an "aside" component into which I want to load `MonitorAside.vue` whenever I am on the `Monitor` page (I am using `vue-router`)

Here's a small rundown.

`src/containers/Full.vue` imports all the main components (including aside) and then uses `router-view` to render the view based on the route.

`src/components/Aside.vue` is the component in question. It contains fixed content but I want its content to dynamically be changed if another component requires to do so.

`src/views/Monitor.vue` is the page in question and thus the page which dynamically needs to inject/swap the content of the `aside` component. **Note that this component is not imported in `Full.vue` but is rendered through the router there.**

`src/views/asides/MonitorAside.vue` is the component I want to be loaded into `Aside.vue` whenever I am on the `Monitor` page.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So whenever vue-router navigates to a different page, you want the content of your `Aside` component to change? You can watch the `$route` value and then render the content depending on your route names, something like:

```
<template>
<div>
    <monitor-aside v-if="page === 'monitor'"></monitor-aside>
    <div v-else>
        <!-- your default aside content -->
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import MonitorAside from '../views/asides/MonitorAside.vue'
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            page: null
        }
    },
    methods: {
        setContent(routeName) {
            if (routeName === 'Monitor') {
                this.page = 'monitor';
            } else {
                this.page = null;
            }
        }
    },
    created() {
        this.setContent(this.$route.name);
    },
    watch: {
        '$route'(to, from) {
            this.setContent(to.name);
        }
    }
    components: {
        MonitorAside
    }
}
</script>
```